# Dep Ensure Doing Nothing Just Loading

Tags: go, dependencies, dep

I have a problem with dep

When i add some dependency for example `github.com/jmoiron/sqlx` this dependency, I have to wait very long, then it just doing nothing, only showing message "Fetching Sources"

I've been waiting for 5 mins and it's not doing anything

*PS: this one still brand new project*

go version go1.11.2 darwin/amd64

dep version 0.50

OS MacOS High Sierra

Any suggestion?

Comment: try dep with verbose option `dep ensure -v`

Comment: yes i've done that, it just showing the process but nothing happen. just stuck

Comment: Try to execute `sudo dep ensure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it work by reinstalling dep

Remove `Gopkg.toml`, `Gopkg.lock`, & `vendor` and re-do dep init again

Remove file from `$GOPATH/pkg/dep` & `$GOPATH/pkg/bin/dep`

Just erase everything about dep.

I Don't know what happen but it works for me

Just make sure you do the dep inside $GOPATH folder